# How to stop and continue same (thread) pthread more than one time.

Tags: c, pthreads

I used in my my program to lock the thread using

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&head->mutex); 
pthread_cond_wait(&head->cond, &head->mutex);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&head->mutex); </i>
```

Then unlock using

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&head->mutex);
pthread_cond_signal(&head->cond);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&head->mutex);
```

I want to put again another condition before thread exit. Until I want stop the thread.

I tried to put

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&head->mutex);
pthread_cond_wait(&head->cond, &head->mutex);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&head->mutex);
```

after first unlocking and signal condition. But the thread have already exited. How can I stop exiting the thread until another condition?

Comment: You tried using two mutex?
One for 1st block and another for the last block
PD: I recommend use of [semaphores](http://greenteapress.com/thinkos/html/thinkos012.html) to block threads

Comment: thanks semaphores are working.

Comment: You can't call `pthread_cond_wait` without first checking to see if there's something to wait for. And calling `pthread_cond_signal` won't work unless you've changed the predicate. You'll notice that your mutex doesn't protect anything, so your code is broken.